# OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onclick, imagebutton

Hello im new to programming, im trying to construct my first simple application, im looking to play a short soundclip on the push of an ImageButton.

while typing out my code i get an error with the statement;

```
 Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

The on click listener is underlined and when i go to the error eclipse tells me that OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type.

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.view;
import android.view.view.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

final ImageButton Button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on clicks

    }
});
```

I read a suggestion that said to add;

```
import android.view.view;
```

aswell as

```
import android.view.view.OnClickListener;
```

These import statements are also highlighted.
Could these errors be caused by how eclipse is set up on my computer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In my apps with onClickListeners the import statement capitlizes the second 'view' like this: import android.view.View.OnClickListener; I don't ever type these import statements though. In eclipse shift+ctrl+o will add any imports you need, and remove any you don't.

Comment: delete your import statement and let eclipse add it for you by right clicking on the OnClickListener

Comment: Your class name cant be like this `main` It should be a Title case like `Main`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For starters, it's always best to let Eclipse manage all imports by tapping Ctrl+Shift+O when you see an import error.

It seems that your problem is due to:

```
import android.view.view;
```

Which should be:

```
import android.view.View;
```

Same goes with android.view.View.OnClickListener.

If you remove the two lines you've manually added and hit Ctrl+Shift+O, everything should fix itself.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies, the problem was fixed by sorting out my capitalisation, i tried removing the manual imports then hitting ctrl+shift+o but that actually removed everything but the bundle and activity imports.

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
import android.view.View.OnclickListener
```

to your `import` section and it should work.

Comment: TYPO: must be a capital C in click.

Answer (score 0):

The second "view" in the import statement is a class (hence, `OnClickListener` is an inner class/interface) and should be capitalised:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Comment: hi ,, @antonyt  please check this if you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345470/onclicklistener-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

make sure your class implements OnClickListener

```
public class main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

Answer (score 0):

if you still have error you can make the class abstract like this
public abstract class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new Android Studio you must declare your new OnClickListener
as View.OnClickListener. Otherwise Android Studio gets confused and won't understand.