# Custom Caller screen in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want custom calling screen I have achieved that but problem is that my screen is not going back when call `cuts.i(..)` want to terminate screen when call cuts. My code is:

```
public class receiver_Call extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        Thread pageTimer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{

                    sleep(1000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    //Toast.makeText(context," text", 5).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent();
                    i.setClass(context, My_call_receiver.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    context.startActivity(i);

                }
            }
        };
        pageTimer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a listener for when the call ends:

```
EndCallListener callListener = new EndCallListener();
TelephonyManager mTM = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

And in your Listener:

```
private class EndCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {}
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {}
        if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {}

    }
}
```

EndCallListener is your class which extends PhoneStateListener (which is defined above)

Comment: what is Endcall listner in this?

Comment: You can use PhoneStateListener
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395633/add-phonestatelistener