# How to detect hangup of an incoming call which was not answered.?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, call, telephonymanager

I found many questions those are describing how to get the call state of a phone call using telephonymanager .And I was following this question in stackoverflow - [How to detect when phone is answered or rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684866/how-to-detect-when-phone-is-answered-or-rejected). But this is to detect the various phone states separately.
**I need to add a alert dialog only when a incoming call hang up with out answered.** How to detect this particular event.?

Comment: I think the answer in that link is perfect for your situation. It sounds like you want to detect rejection of an incoming call

Answer (score 3):

Android 5.0 and above may send duplicate events. You may consider keeping the previous state for comparison -

```
private class PhoneStateChangeListener extends PhoneStateListener {

static final int IDLE = 0;
static final int OFFHOOK = 1;
static final int RINGING = 2;
int lastState = IDLE;

@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    switch(state){
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
             lastState = RINGING;
             break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
             lastState = OFFHOOK;
             break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
             if (lastState == RINGING) {
                 // Process for call hangup without being answered
             }
             lastState = IDLE;
             break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: my broadcast listener class can listen to the event while my app is not running?

Comment: Yes, with a full setup like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395633/add-phonestatelistener

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
private class PhoneStateChangeListener extends PhoneStateListener {
boolean isAnswered = false;
@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    switch(state){
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
             isAnswered  = false;
             break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
             isAnswered=true;
             break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
             if(isAnswered == false)
             //Call hangup without answered
             break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks you for the quick response. I have one more doubt that how to add Alert Dialog Box in above described code. It's required context parameter.And when i am trying to do with it Fatal error occured.