# PhoneStateListener not working on Physical S7 Edge, but works in Nexus 4 Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, samsung-mobile, phone-state-listener

In the onCreate() method of a Service, I created a PhoneStateListener to capture service status change events, and associate it to the TelephoneManager:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState) {
            //CODE TO HANDLING SERVICE STATE EVENT
        }
    }

    tel.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);
}
```

This code captures the service state events rightly in a Nexus 4 Virtual Device w/Gingerbread, but when I try this in a physical S7 Edge w/Marshmallow, the event isn't catched.

The following are the permissions that have my app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Do you know why the events isn't catched in the Marshmallow device?

Comment: have you requested rights in runtime in a proper way? If no - you should :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13396210/6689101

Comment: Yeah, that's the first I do, and the Phone permissions are granted to the app in the Marshmallow.