# Difference between a BroadcastReceiver and a PhoneStateListener to listen to calls

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I know, this may seem alike a "trivial" question, but there is a bit of confusion since there are multiple options available.

I want to listen to phone calls and have found two solutions for doing the same:

- [`BroadcastReceiver` to listen to the calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/how-to-detect-incoming-calls-in-an-android-device/15564021#15564021)
- [A `PhoneStateListener` that works with the `TelephonyManager`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395633/add-phonestatelistener)

These seem to be mutually exclusive. What solution should I prefer? Do they really cater to different use cases? If so, what might they be?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `BroadcastReceiver` your application does not need to be running. Android broadcasts call-related events and your `BroadcastReceiver` will be notified of call-related events and you can do whatever you want to do.

If you use a `PhoneStateListener`, your application must be running. You will need an `Activity` or a `Service` that creates the `PhoneStateListener` and registers it. Your `PhoneStateListener` will then be notified of call-related events. When your app is finished or killed by Android you will no longer receive any call-related events.