# jump to custom view when phone rings

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I need to implement a feature, that will jump to custom view when phone rings. I had the following idea:

- register a listener to listen phone ring
- jump to custom view after 1s when phone ring has been detected

But it can't work well at some android version. Can you give me some ideas?

Comment: Post code, show log, describe problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 8 added some actions related to this.

The `ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS` permission allows your app to answer incoming phone calls programmatically. To handle an incoming phone call in your app, you can use the `acceptRingingCall()` method. You could use this method to implement your custom view.

These permission are both classified as dangerous however and are both part of the `PHONE` permission group.

Comment: Burton.
thanks for your recommendation. but My test android version is 4.4,which I have to be compatible with it.

Comment: Might want to check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395633/add-phonestatelistener