# TelephonyManager deprecated listen() CALL_STATE_RINGING on android 12

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager, android-12

I'd like to listen if there's a phone call happening while my app is in the foreground.

It was like this before but now listen() is deprecated:

```
val tm = context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
            tm.listen(object : PhoneStateListener() {
                override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, phoneNumber: String?) {
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, phoneNumber)
                    when (state) {
                        TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING -> transcribingAudioConsumer.stopTranscription(null)
                        else -> {}
                    }
                }
            }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)
```

I tried something like this but I couldn't find the correct way to implement it.

```
         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                        tm.registerTelephonyCallback({ it.run() }, MyPhoneStateListener())
                    }
```

```
  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    class MyPhoneStateListener : TelephonyCallback(), TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener {
        override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int) {
            when (state) {
                TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING -> {
                    Timber.e("omg RING")
                }

                TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
                    Timber.e("omg hook")
                }
                TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                    Timber.e("omg idle")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since the listen method is deprecated since api 31 android 12 I made a simple way to listen to the telephony callbacks.

```kotlin
val telephonyManager: TelephonyManager =
    context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
    telephonyManager.registerTelephonyCallback(
        context.mainExecutor,
        object : TelephonyCallback(), TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener {
            override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int) {
            }
        })
} else {
    telephonyManager.listen(object : PhoneStateListener() {
        override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, phoneNumber: String?) {
        }
    }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)
}
```

Note that the new callback does not include a phone number.
At least for broadcast receiver the phone number can be retrieved via

```
intent.extras.getString("incoming_number")
```

Comment: after adding, i am receiving security exception in Android 12, Do we need to add any permissions in Android 12?

Comment: @RaviGadipudi, you need to check READ_PHONE_STATE permission

`private fun isReadPhoneStateGranted() = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`

Comment: Yes, Found it thru behavioural changes of Android 12 document. Thanks for the reply. @OrcunSevsay

Comment: can anyone convert this code to java? This is because i do not understand kotlin. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want this code in Java, please someone share it ASAP

Comment: @xdbas How can I get phone number  with this new callback? Is there any way?

Answer (score 4):

ServiceReceiver(Java)

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.telephony.TelephonyCallback;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    registerCustomTelephonyCallback(context);
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
class CustomTelephonyCallback extends TelephonyCallback implements TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener {
    private CallBack mCallBack;

    public CustomTelephonyCallback(CallBack callBack) {
        mCallBack = callBack;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state) {

        mCallBack.callStateChanged(state);

    }
}


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
public void registerCustomTelephonyCallback(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    telephony.registerTelephonyCallback(context.getMainExecutor(), new CustomTelephonyCallback(new CallBack() {
        @Override
        public void callStateChanged(int state) {

            int myState=state;

        }
    }));


}

interface CallBack {
    void callStateChanged(int state);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks but onReceive never called.I am testing it on android emulator.

Comment: The written code only works on android 12. Make sure your device is android 12.

Comment: it works, thank you! But test on physical device, using emulator appear an error!

Comment: I am not able to get onRecieve on my android 12 device, could someone please share the full code in java - starting from creating a ServiceRequestor object. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I used what you did and android 12 emulator also worked.I used this for versions less than android 12 I hope it works.

```
    class MyPhoneStateListener() : PhoneStateListener() {
    override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, incomingNumber: String) {
        when (state) {
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                Log.e("MyPhoneStateListener", "IDLE")
            
            }
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
                Log.e("MyPhoneStateListener", "OFFHOOK")
            }
            TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING -> {
                Log.e("MyPhoneStateListener", "RINGING")
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I used this to listen to the call

---

```
 phoneListener = MyPhoneStateListener()
             var telephony: TelephonyManager? = null
                telephony = context
                    .getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager?

                telephony!!.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)
```

finally you should make a ServiceReceiver class like here.
[Add PhoneStateListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395633/add-phonestatelistener/13396210#13396210)

Android 12 :I found an example here. I hope it works for you. https://note.com/koh_49/n/n94a5c2ae3aa2

```
  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
class CustomTelephonyCallback(private val func: (state: Int) -> Unit) :
TelephonyCallback(),
TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener {
    override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int) {
        func(state)
    }
}
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
fun registerCustomTelephonyCallback(){

     var callback: CustomTelephonyCallback? = null


        (getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as? TelephonyManager)?.
        registerTelephonyCallback(
            mainExecutor,
            CustomTelephonyCallback {
                //
                var state=it
             

            }.also {
                callback = it
            }
        )


}
```

Manifest

```
    <receiver android:name=".data.service.receiver.ServiceReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

ServiceReceiver

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.telephony.TelephonyCallback
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getMainExecutor


class ServiceReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

    registerCustomTelephonyCallback(context)


}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
class CustomTelephonyCallback(private val func: (state: Int) -> Unit) :
    TelephonyCallback(),
    TelephonyCallback.CallStateListener {
    override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int) {
        func(state)
    }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
fun registerCustomTelephonyCallback(context: Context?){

    var callback: CustomTelephonyCallback? = null

    (context?.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as? TelephonyManager)?.
    registerTelephonyCallback(
        getMainExecutor(context),
        CustomTelephonyCallback {
            //
            var state=it


        }.also {
            callback = it
        }
    )


}
```

}

Comment: `telephony.listen()` and PhoneStateListener() are deprecated. I know it's still working on Android 12, but I'd like to integrate with `registerTelephonyCallback(Executor, TelephonyCallback)`.

Comment: `Deprecated Use registerTelephonyCallback(Executor, TelephonyCallback).
Params:
listener – The PhoneStateListener object to register (or unregister)
events – The telephony state(s) of interest to the listener, as a bitwise-OR combination of PhoneStateListener LISTEN_ flags.`


You may see Deprecated and suggestion message under TelephonyManager.java `listen(..)` class

Comment: Thank you for your answer.yes I saw it deprecated "telephony.listen()" while using it in my project, then I started researching.   I found your question and solution. This use "registerTelephonyCallback(Executor, TelephonyCallback" is not correct?. I m use your solution now for android 12

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to build it with `TelephonyCallback` instead of `telephony.listen()` and `PhoneStateListener`. If you can help me to find how to integrate with `TelephonyCallback`, I'll be appreciated

Comment: What's `mainExecutor` that you've shared? @Enes BAŞKAYA

Comment: ı m use "mainExecutor" in my class. class MyCallScreeningService : CallScreeningService() .  I call it from within this class of android. package 
android.content; 
.... 
/** * Proxying implementation of Context that simply delegates all of its calls to * another Context. Can be subclassed to modify behavior without changing * the original Context. */ 
public class ContextWrapper extends Context { 
.... 
@Override public Executor getMainExecutor() { return mBase.getMainExecutor(); 
}

Comment: When I import it in my  receiver class, it imports from this package."import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getMainExecutor"

Comment: Could you also share your Receiver class and how you call it in Manifest, please?

Comment: I updated my answer.There was no receiver class in my project.  I wrote this and tried it now it works.@Orcun Sevsay

Comment: Greate Answer. Thanks a lot! It works pretty good!

Comment: You are welcome.I'm glad it was useful. I wish you good work.

Comment: @EnesBAŞKAYA Can you provide the same snippet for JAVA?

Comment: I shared an example for Java. Hope it helps you @Saurabh

Comment: @EnesBAŞKAYA Thanks a lot mate. Can we use this like registering inside activity instead of manifest?

Comment: @Saurabh You're welcome .I've never done this before but you can send the data in the receiver class to the relevant activity