# How to get the phone number during an incoming and outgoing call?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I use a class that extends BroadcastReceiver. how can I get the phone number during an incoming or outgoing call?

This is my department:

```
public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context , Intent intent) {
     
        if (intent.getStringExtra( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE ).equals( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK )) {
          //Call started

        } else if (intent.getStringExtra( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE ).equals( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE )) {
           //Call ended

        } else if (intent.getStringExtra( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE ).equals( TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING )) {
             //Incoming call
            }
    } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get it this way.

```
public class CallRecevier extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
                    super.onCallStateChanged(state, phoneNumber);
                    if (state == 1 || state == 2) {
                        if (phoneNumber != null && !phoneNumber.equals("")) {
                           Tİmber.e("Call Number: %s",phoneNumber);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Timber.e("Error: %s", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And, along with this, don’t forget to add
1. Below permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
2. And below intent-filter within your BroadcastReceiver declaration in manifest.xml <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: phone state listener is now deprecated. what is other solution

Comment: this android 12 version solution..[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571012/telephonymanager-deprecated-listen-call-state-ringing-on-android-12)