# How to retrieve incoming and outgoing phone number in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, deprecated, telephonymanager

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    phnNbr = intent?.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER).toString()
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    val telephony =
        context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    telephony.listen(object : PhoneStateListener() {
        override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, incomingNumber: String) {
//                        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber)
            println("incomingNumber API>28: $incomingNumber")
            phnNbr = incomingNumber
        }
    }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)
}
```

i am getting blank string using this code in API 30

> I/System.out:
> incomingNumber API>28:

also the onCallStateChanged has been depreated for android 12, and the TelephonyCallback cannot provide the phone number. i also would like to know a workaround for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571012/telephonymanager-deprecated-listen-call-state-ringing-on-android-12

Comment: Actually i need the Phone Number. I tested my code further and found out this gives the number only if the app is open. asked another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70351893/telephony-listen-phonestatelistener-not-working-when-app-is-closed
Thanks for the suggestion though