# telephony.listen , phoneStateListener not working when app is closed

Tags: android, kotlin, telephony, phone-state-listener

This PhoneStateListener only works if the app is open for API>28(P) but i want the incoming/outgoing phone number even if the app is closed just like it works in API<=28(P).
i am getting the phone number if the app is open at the time of call, but otherwise number is coming as blank.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                phnNbr = intent?.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER).toString()
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                val telephony =
                    context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
                telephony.listen(object : PhoneStateListener() {
                    override fun onCallStateChanged(state: Int, incomingNumber: String) {
                        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber)
                        println("incomingNumber API>28: $incomingNumber")
                        phnNbr = incomingNumber
                    }
                }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using onCallStateChanged as i learned from the documentation that the `getStringExtra(EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)` is deprecated in SDK<= Android P. But to my surprise, as I had READ_PHONE_NUMBERS & READ_CALL_LOG permissions, the old way `getStringExtra(EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)` worked for me and this also solved wrong responses when operating Sim 2. Just be sure to handle multiple calls to  `fun onReceive` of the BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: For me broadcast receiver is not working if app is idle for long time

Comment: How long appoximately?

Comment: In some devices 30 to 50 minutes in some devices after 3 or 4 hours, Now I used foreground service it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

It is normal behavior for Android OS to protect user privacy against malicious apps from stealing user information. However, You can resolve the problem by using a *System Event Broadcast Receiver* to be notified of incoming phone calls. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/how-to-detect-incoming-calls-in-an-android-device/15564021) is a good example to follow. The example is not enough and applicable for current android API levels and you need to have a [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) when a call is received then run the Foreground Service and execute your codes.

Comment: i have written this code inside `override fun onReceive`  in MyCallReceiver class which extends BroadcastReceiver. Should this work?

Comment: @RausonAli you can try it.

Comment: My approach works but when the app is not used for long time them outgoing calls do not give phone nbr first but then it starts in the next call done within a short interval

Comment: @RausonAli am facing same issue that  you faced, can you pls share your answer so that  it will be helpful for me and everyone

Comment: @Curvegraph Hope my answer helps.

Comment: @RausonAli I will try today, thanks for updating the answer