# How support PhoneStateListener for APIs below 31?

Tags: android, kotlin, phone-state-listener

I have discovered that the code of my application has been deprecated. I was using `PhoneStateListener` class but now I see that this decreasing for API 31 and that now we have to use `TelephonyCallback` class. Is there any chance that the `PhoneStateListener` class is completely eliminated and my App is unwreneless for API versions below 31? Is there a compatibility library as it happens for the `LocalDateTime` class? Or what extent should I take to solve this problem? It is important to declare that the use of this class is of vital importance for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that deprecated doesn't mean the class/method/function is no longer usable, it's just that it's recommended you do not use it anymore. It *may* go away in the future, but it won't be immediate.

That being said, you're going to want to move to the `TelephonyCallback` class sooner than later in case the `PhoneStateListener` class is removed.

Comment: If i move to TelephonyCallback I will leave apis below 31 without support and that is not the idea

Comment: You can add a check on the version code of the app to use the proper class, like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69571012/telephonymanager-deprecated-listen-call-state-ringing-on-android-12

Comment: I have seen thath question but i have fear that my app be unusable

Comment: Why are you worried about the app being unusable? Is it an issue of the new class not doing what you want or that the version check won't work?